# What is the difference between x86_64 and i386?

Tags: architecture

What is the difference? Under what category does my system fall into? I want to download Fedora12 and it shows me these options. Which one should I download?

I have a Sony Vaio cr36g/b with an Intel Core 2 Duo 8100 processor.

Comment: Intel core 2 duo is 64 bits processor.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`x86_64` is for 64 bit processors.
`i386` is for 32 bit processors.

All Core 2 Duos are capable of running 64 bit operating systems and 32 bit operating systems.

You want `x86_64` as it will run better and allow you to have more RAM in the future, although if you are worried about compatibility, you could use `i386`. Personally I haven't had any problems with `x86_64` on Linux.

Comment: mine is core 2 duo 8100. Is it capable of running 64 bit OS?

Comment: Yes. All Core 2 Duos are.

Comment: Was it really necessary to ask "mine is core 2 duo 8100. Is it capable of running 64 bit OS?" in every single answer? I mean come on...

Comment: Necessary, no.  But it does alert the person that their comment was replied to so they can follow up on the new comment.

Answer (score 7):

**x86_64** refers to 64-bit processors. **i386** refers to 32-bit processors.

If you really do have an Intel Core 2 Duo, then it is a 64-bit processor. Some of the Intel Core processors were 32-bit. You can download either or - it depends if you want to run the 64-bit version. It gives you advantages of being able to use more memory (> 4GB per process, > 4GB in total without leveraging PAE) and in some instances will operate more quickly (and others more slowly).

Comment: mine is core 2 duo 8100. Is it capable of running 64 bit OS?

Comment: @Aditya: Yes it is.